# neo4j querying goes wrong after 3 or more matches

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I am doing a neo4j project at the moment for a timetabling system I have created all my nodes and relationships for the database

but once I try to create a query eg to get a certain lecture on a certain day in a certain room at a certain time with a certain lecturer it will just not do it

here is my cypher file for creating nodes and relationships

```
CREATE (ServerSideRad:Module{Name:"Server Side Rad"})
CREATE (MobileAppDevelopment:Module{Name:"Mobile APP Development"})
CREATE (GraphTheory:Module{Name:"Graph Theory"})
CREATE (DatabaseManagementSystems:Module{Name:"Database Management Systems"})
CREATE (SoftwareTesting:Module{Name:"Software Testing"})
CREATE (FinalYearProject:Module{Name:"Final Year Project"})

CREATE (GPrefab01:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab01"})
CREATE (GPrefab02:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab02"})
CREATE (GPrefab03:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab03"})
CREATE (GPrefab04:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab04"})
CREATE (GPrefab05:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab05"})
CREATE (GPrefab06:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab06"})
CREATE (GPrefab07:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab07"})
CREATE (GPrefab08:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab08"})
CREATE (GPrefab09:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab09"})
CREATE (GPrefab10:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab10"})
CREATE (GPrefab18:Rooms{Name:"G Prefab18"})
CREATE (GReceptionFoyerNewBuilding:Rooms{Name:"G Reception Foyer New Building"})
CREATE (G0130HydraulicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0130 Hydraulics Lab"})
CREATE (G0131DissectionLab:Rooms{Name:"G0131 Dissection Lab"})
CREATE (G0141AMTLab:Rooms{Name:"G0141 AMT Lab"})
CREATE (G0143EngSciLab:Rooms{Name:"G0143 Eng Sci Lab"})
CREATE (G0145:Rooms{Name:"G0145"})
CREATE (G0148ConcreteLab:Rooms{Name:"G0148 Concrete Lab"})
CREATE (G0150CivilStructuresLab:Rooms{Name:"G0150 Civil Structures Lab"})
CREATE (G0152EnvironmentalLab:Rooms{Name:"G0152 Environmental Lab"})
CREATE (G0153:Rooms{Name:"G0153"})
CREATE (G0154:Rooms{Name:"G0154"})
CREATE (G0156:Rooms{Name:"G0156"})
CREATE (G0157:Rooms{Name:"G0157"})
CREATE (G0158:Rooms{Name:"G0158"})
CREATE (G0159:Rooms{Name:"G0159"})
CREATE (G0162:Rooms{Name:"G0162"})
CREATE (G0165:Rooms{Name:"G0165"})
CREATE (G0208:Rooms{Name:"G0208"})
CREATE (G0209:Rooms{Name:"G0209"})
CREATE (G0210NimbusLab:Rooms{Name:"G0210 Nimbus Lab"})
CREATE (G0213bBurrenLab:Rooms{Name:"G0213b Burren Lab"})
CREATE (G0215ArannLab:Rooms{Name:"G0215 Arann Lab"})
CREATE (G0217CorribLab:Rooms{Name:"G0217 Corrib Lab"})
CREATE (G0223:Rooms{Name:"G0223"})
CREATE (G0224ComputerandCADLab:Rooms{Name:"G0224 Computer and CAD Lab"})
CREATE (G0225CivilEngProjectRoom:Rooms{Name:"G0225 Civil Eng Project Room"})
CREATE (G0226ProjectRoom:Rooms{Name:"G0226 Project Room"})
CREATE (G0227ComputerandCADLab:Rooms{Name:"G0227 Computer and CAD Lab"})
CREATE (G0228ArchitectualStudio:Rooms{Name:"G0228 Architectual Studio"})
CREATE (G0229ProjectRoom:Rooms{Name:"G0229 Project Room"})
CREATE (G0230ProjectRoom:Rooms{Name:"G0230 Project Room"})
CREATE (G0231b:Rooms{Name:"G0231b"})
CREATE (G0301AquaticEcologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0301 Aquatic Ecology Lab"})
CREATE (G0304CR6GeneralScienceLab:Rooms{Name:"G0304 CR6  General Science Lab"})
CREATE (G0306BiologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0306 Biology Lab"})
CREATE (G0309BiologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0309 Biology Lab"})
CREATE (G0310BiologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0310 Biology Lab"})
CREATE (G0315aPhysicstLab:Rooms{Name:"G0315a Physicst Lab"})
CREATE (G0315bPhysicstLab:Rooms{Name:"G0315b Physicst Lab"})
CREATE (G0315cPhysicstLab:Rooms{Name:"G0315c Physicst Lab"})
CREATE (G0318AquaticScienceLab:Rooms{Name:"G0318 Aquatic Science Lab"})
CREATE (G0347ExamRoom:Rooms{Name:"G0347 Exam Room"})
CREATE (G0351:Rooms{Name:"G0351"})
CREATE (G0364:Rooms{Name:"G0364"})
CREATE (G0365:Rooms{Name:"G0365"})
CREATE (G0366:Rooms{Name:"G0366"})
CREATE (G0367a:Rooms{Name:"G0367a"})
CREATE (G0367b:Rooms{Name:"G0367b"})
CREATE (G0368:Rooms{Name:"G0368"})
CREATE (G0369:Rooms{Name:"G0369"})
CREATE (G0370:Rooms{Name:"G0370"})
CREATE (G0373:Rooms{Name:"G0373"})
CREATE (G0374:Rooms{Name:"G0374"})
CREATE (G0375:Rooms{Name:"G0375"})
CREATE (G0376:Rooms{Name:"G0376"})
CREATE (G0377:Rooms{Name:"G0377"})
CREATE (G0378:Rooms{Name:"G0378"})
CREATE (G0379:Rooms{Name:"G0379"})
CREATE (G0380:Rooms{Name:"G0380"})
CREATE (G0402BiochemistryLab:Rooms{Name:"G0402 Biochemistry Lab"})
CREATE (G0405BiochemChemistryLab:Rooms{Name:"G0405 BiochemChemistry Lab"})
CREATE (G0411ChromotographyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0411 Chromotography Lab"})
CREATE (G0422ElectroChemLab:Rooms{Name:"G0422 Electro Chem Lab"})
CREATE (G0436CR5:Rooms{Name:"G0436 CR5"})
CREATE (G0450GreyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0450 Grey Lab"})
CREATE (G0451MicrobiologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0451 Microbiology Lab"})
CREATE (G0470ComputingPracticalLab:Rooms{Name:"G0470 Computing Practical Lab"})
CREATE (G0471MedLab:Rooms{Name:"G0471 Med Lab"})
CREATE (G0475MolecularBiologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0475 Molecular Biology Lab"})
CREATE (G0476FoodScienceLabWineRoom:Rooms{Name:"G0476 Food Science LabWine Room"})
CREATE (G0478GreenLab:Rooms{Name:"G0478 Green Lab"})
CREATE (G0479BlueLab:Rooms{Name:"G0479 Blue Lab"})
CREATE (G0480CR7:Rooms{Name:"G0480 CR7"})
CREATE (G0481CR4:Rooms{Name:"G0481 CR4"})
CREATE (G0482CR3:Rooms{Name:"G0482 CR3"})
CREATE (G0483CR2:Rooms{Name:"G0483 CR2"})
CREATE (G0484CR1:Rooms{Name:"G0484 CR1"})
CREATE (G0501ElectronicCADLab:Rooms{Name:"G0501 Electronic CAD Lab"})
CREATE (G0502PhysicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0502 Physics Lab"})
CREATE (G0506ComputerLab:Rooms{Name:"G0506 Computer Lab"})
CREATE (G0507ComputerLab:Rooms{Name:"G0507 Computer Lab"})
CREATE (G0508ComputerLab:Rooms{Name:"G0508 Computer Lab"})
CREATE (G0511Lab:Rooms{Name:"G0511 Lab"})
CREATE (G05267CityofGalwayTrainingRestAndampBar:Rooms{Name:"G05267 City of Galway Training Rest &amp; Bar"})
CREATE (G05267IQBar:Rooms{Name:"G05267 IQ Bar"})
CREATE (G0550Unit6:Rooms{Name:"G0550 Unit 6"})
CREATE (G0552DemoTheatre:Rooms{Name:"G0552 Demo Theatre"})
CREATE (G0559Unit8PastryKitchen:Rooms{Name:"G0559 Unit 8 Pastry Kitchen"})
CREATE (G0560AccommodationandFrontOfficeSuite:Rooms{Name:"G0560 Accommodation and Front Office Suite"})
CREATE (G0602ChemistryLab:Rooms{Name:"G0602 Chemistry Lab"})
CREATE (G0603Lab:Rooms{Name:"G0603 Lab"})
CREATE (G0610OrganicChemistryLab:Rooms{Name:"G0610 Organic Chemistry Lab"})
CREATE (G0615Unit9:Rooms{Name:"G0615 Unit 9"})
CREATE (G0616Unit1:Rooms{Name:"G0616 Unit 1"})
CREATE (G0623Unit3:Rooms{Name:"G0623 Unit 3"})
CREATE (G0625Unit4:Rooms{Name:"G0625 Unit 4"})
CREATE (G0626Unit5:Rooms{Name:"G0626 Unit 5"})
CREATE (G0629MicrobiologyLab:Rooms{Name:"G0629 Microbiology Lab"})
CREATE (G0632RetailLab:Rooms{Name:"G0632 Retail Lab"})
CREATE (G0637Unit:Rooms{Name:"G0637 Unit"})
CREATE (G0701PhysicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0701 Physics Lab"})
CREATE (G0702PhysicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0702 Physics Lab"})
CREATE (G0703PhysicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0703 Physics Lab"})
CREATE (G0704PhysicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0704 Physics Lab"})
CREATE (G0707CADCAMLab:Rooms{Name:"G0707 CADCAM Lab"})
CREATE (G0724bWS:Rooms{Name:"G0724b WS"})
CREATE (G0724CWSCNCPenFactory:Rooms{Name:"G0724C WS CNCPen Factory"})
CREATE (G0724dEnergyFluidLab:Rooms{Name:"G0724d Energy Fluid Lab"})
CREATE (G0728aGarage:Rooms{Name:"G0728a Garage"})
CREATE (G0731WiringandMotorControlInstallationWorkshop:Rooms{Name:"G0731 Wiring and Motor Control Installation Workshop"})
CREATE (G0736ElectricalandElectronicProjectsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0736 Electrical and Electronic Projects Lab"})
CREATE (G0813ComputerLabPBL:Rooms{Name:"G0813 Computer LabPBL"})
CREATE (G0827ElectronicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0827 Electronics Lab"})
CREATE (G0828ElectronicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0828 Electronics Lab"})
CREATE (G0830ElectronicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0830 Electronics Lab"})
CREATE (G0832ElectronicsLab:Rooms{Name:"G0832 Electronics Lab"})
CREATE (G0834ComputerLabPBL:Rooms{Name:"G0834 Computer LabPBL"})
CREATE (G0835InfoTechnologyComputerLab:Rooms{Name:"G0835 Info Technology Computer Lab"})
CREATE (G0837:Rooms{Name:"G0837"})
CREATE (G0841WineGeeseTrainingBar:Rooms{Name:"G0841 Wine Geese Training Bar"})
CREATE (G0842ConnemaraUpstairsTrainingRest:Rooms{Name:"G0842 Connemara Upstairs Training Rest"})
CREATE (G0843Unit:Rooms{Name:"G0843 Unit"})
CREATE (G0903:Rooms{Name:"G0903"})
CREATE (G0907LanguageLab:Rooms{Name:"G0907 Language Lab"})
CREATE (G0910LanguageLab:Rooms{Name:"G0910 Language Lab"})
CREATE (G0938:Rooms{Name:"G0938"})
CREATE (G0939:Rooms{Name:"G0939"})
CREATE (G0940:Rooms{Name:"G0940"})
CREATE (G0941:Rooms{Name:"G0941"})
CREATE (G0994:Rooms{Name:"G0994"})
CREATE (G0995:Rooms{Name:"G0995"})
CREATE (G0996:Rooms{Name:"G0996"})
CREATE (G0997:Rooms{Name:"G0997"})
CREATE (G1000BlueTheatre:Rooms{Name:"G1000 Blue Theatre"})
CREATE (G1031:Rooms{Name:"G1031"})
CREATE (G1032:Rooms{Name:"G1032"})
CREATE (G1033:Rooms{Name:"G1033"})
CREATE (G1034:Rooms{Name:"G1034"})
CREATE (G1035:Rooms{Name:"G1035"})
CREATE (G1036:Rooms{Name:"G1036"})
CREATE (G1039:Rooms{Name:"G1039"})
CREATE (G1041VideoConferenceRoom:Rooms{Name:"G1041 Video Conference Room"})

CREATE (Monday:Days{Name:"Monday"})
CREATE (Tuesday:Days{Name:"Tuesday"})
CREATE (Wednesday:Days{Name:"Wednesday"})
CREATE (Thursday:Days{Name:"Thursday"})
CREATE (Friday:Days{Name:"Friday"})

CREATE (SoftwareDevelopmentL7Yr3:Courses{Name:"Software Development L7 Yr3"})

CREATE (Slot1:Times{Name:"9am-10Am"})
CREATE (Slot2:Times{Name:"10am-11Am"})
CREATE (Slot3:Times{Name:"11am-12pm"})
CREATE (Slot4:Times{Name:"12pm-1pm"})
CREATE (Slot5:Times{Name:"1pm-2pm"})
CREATE (Slot6:Times{Name:"2pm-3pm"})
CREATE (Slot7:Times{Name:"3pm-4pm"})
CREATE (Slot8:Times{Name:"4pm-5pm"})
CREATE (Slot9:Times{Name:"5pm-6pm"})

CREATE (Slot10:Times{Name:"9am-11Am"})
CREATE (Slot11:Times{Name:"11am-1pm"})
CREATE (Slot12:Times{Name:"1pm-3pm"})
CREATE (Slot13:Times{Name:"3pm-5pm"})
CREATE (Slot14:Times{Name:"10am-12pm"})
CREATE (Slot15:Times{Name:"12pm-2pm"})
CREATE (Slot16:Times{Name:"2pm-4pm"})
CREATE (Slot17:Times{Name:"4pm-6pm"})


CREATE (MartinHynes:Lecturers{Name:"Martin Hynes"})
CREATE (IanMcLoughlin:Lecturers{Name:"Ian McLoughlin"})
CREATE (DamienCostello:Lecturers{Name:"Damien costello"})
CREATE (DeidreODonovan:Lecturers{Name:"Deidre O'Donovan"})
CREATE (GerardHarrison:Lecturers{Name:"Gerard Harrison"})

CREATE (GroupA:Groups{Name:"GroupA"})
CREATE (GroupB:Groups{Name:"GroupB"})
CREATE (GroupC:Groups{Name:"GroupC"})
CREATE (GroupAll:Groups{Name:"All Groups"})

CREATE (Lecture:Lesson{Name:"lecture"})
CREATE (Lab:Lesson{Name:"Lab"}) 



CREATE(IanMcLoughlin)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupA),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(GPrefab05),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot6),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Monday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(GraphTheory)

 CREATE(DeidreODonovan)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0940),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot2),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Monday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(DatabaseManagementSystems)

 CREATE(DamienCostello)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0223),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot4),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Monday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(MobileAppDevelopment)

 CREATE(MartinHynes)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupA),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0481CR4),
 (Lab)-[:FROM]->(Slot17),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Monday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(SoftwareTesting)

 CREATE(GerardHarrison)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0436CR5),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot17),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Monday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(ServerSideRad)

 CREATE(MartinHynes)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0436CR5),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot10),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(SoftwareTesting)

 CREATE(DeidreODonovan)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupA),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0940),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot10),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(DatabaseManagementSystems)

  CREATE(DamienCostello)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupA),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0470ComputingPracticalLab),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot11),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(MobileAppDevelopment)

 CREATE(DeidreODonovan)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0482CR3),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot11),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(DatabaseManagementSystems)

 CREATE(IanMcLoughlin)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupB),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0379),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot4),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(GraphTheory)

  CREATE(MartinHynes)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupB),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0436CR5),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot16),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(SoftwareTesting)

 CREATE(GerardHarrison)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0436CR5),
 (Lab)-[:At]->(Slot17),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Tuesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(ServerSideRad)



 CREATE(IanMcLoughlin)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0162),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot1),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Wednesday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(GraphTheory)

 CREATE(IanMcLoughlin)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0938),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot2),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Wednesday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(GraphTheory)

 CREATE(DamienCostello)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0208),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot3),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Wednesday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(FinalYearProject)

 CREATE(GerardHarrison)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0997),
 (Lecture)-[:At]->(Slot5),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Wednesday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(ServerSideRad)

 CREATE(MartinHynes)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0939),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot7),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Wednesday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(SoftwareTesting)

 CREATE(DeidreODonovan)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0995),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot8),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Wednesday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(DatabaseManagementSystems)



 CREATE(DamienCostello)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupB),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0470ComputingPracticalLab),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot10),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Thursay),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(MobileAppDevelopment)

 CREATE(DamienCostello)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0470ComputingPracticalLab),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot11),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Thursay),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(MobileAppDevelopment)

 CREATE(DeidreODonovan)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0483CR2),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot16),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Thursay),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(DatabaseManagementSystems)

 CREATE(GerardHarrison)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupC),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0436CR5),
 (Lab)-[:At]->(Slot16),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Thursay),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(ServerSideRad)



 CREATE(DeidreODonovan)-[:TEACHES]->(Lab),
 (Lab)-[:TO]->(GroupB),
 (Lab)-[:IN]->(G0482CR3),
 (Lab)-[:AT]->(Slot10),
 (Lab)-[:ON]->(Friday),
 (Lab)-[:FOR]->(DatabaseManagementSystems)

 CREATE(IanMcLoughlin)-[:TEACHES]->(Lecture),
 (Lecture)-[:TO]->(GroupAll),
 (Lecture)-[:IN]->(G0208),
 (Lecture)-[:AT]->(Slot3),
 (Lecture)-[:ON]->(Friday),
 (Lecture)-[:FOR]->(GraphTheory)
```

once I load this in. I then Try to query one of the relationships
like so

```
MATCH p=(n:Lecturers{ Name:"Deidre O'Donovan"})-[r:TEACHES]-
(l:Lesson{ Name:"Lab"})-[:ON]->(d:Days{Name:"Tuesday"})-[:IN]->
(h:Rooms{ Name:"G0482 CR3"}) RETURN p
```

But it will just keep giving blank screen back saying (no changes, no records)
any help greatly appreciated as I have been at this the last two days

Answer (score 3):

One of your main problems is that the data model used by your data creation query is different than the one you use for your second query. So, of course the second query does not match anything.

Your data creation query has (only) 2 `Lesson` nodes, and *every* relationship is *directly* connected to one of those nodes.

In your second query, most of the relationships are not directly connected to the 2 `Lesson` nodes. But that query's data model is also very flawed, since every `Rooms` node is directly related to one of the 5 `Days` nodes, which means once you traverse to a `Days` node, you have relationships to all `Rooms` nodes related to that day (for all lecturers and lessons). There is no way you can tell which room is used for any lesson by any lecturer.

You also have typos in your data creation query. "Thursay" should be "Thursday".

Therefore, you need to decide on a workable data model and use it consistently.